# Set or change vertical position of the cursor

Tags: bash

As far as I know, it is possible to move the cursor to the left using the backspace sequence in an *echo*. But is there any possibility to change the vertical position of the cursor, using an *echo*?

Comment: See: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This section describes the ANSI escape sequences:

- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Examples:

```
echo -en "\033[s\033[7B\033[1;34m 7 lines down violet \033[u\033[0m"
echo -en "\033[s\033[7A\033[1;32m 7 lines up green \033[u\033[0m"
```

And this section describes the tput utility:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

For a demonstration, see *The floating clock* in your terminal:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/clockt.html

An example script taken from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/spice-up-your-unix-linux-shell-scripts.html:

```
#!/bin/bash

tput clear      # clear the screen

tput cup 3 15   # Move cursor to screen location X,Y (top left is 0,0)

tput setaf 3    # Set a foreground colour using ANSI escape
echo "XYX Corp LTD."
tput sgr0

tput cup 5 17
tput rev        # Set reverse video mode
echo "M A I N - M E N U"
tput sgr0

tput cup 7 15; echo "1. User Management"
tput cup 8 15; echo "2. Service Management"
tput cup 9 15; echo "3. Process Management"
tput cup 10 15; echo "4. Backup"

tput bold       # Set bold mode 
tput cup 12 15
read -p "Enter your choice [1-4] " choice

tput clear
tput sgr0
tput rc
```

[image: tput example]

Answer (score 9):

Using `echo` will restrict you to a specific terminal type. It is better to use `tput`.

```
tput cup 10 4; echo there
```

will put cursor on row 10 column 4 and print “there” at that position.

For more elementary movements you have `tput cub1` to move left, `tput cuf1` to move right, `tput cuu1` to move up and `tput cud1` to move the cursor down.

Comment: …and another demonstration of tldp having incomplete answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as noted by miku, ANSI terminal escapes, or a little cleaner is tput which should work on any terminal:

```
tput cuu 1             # move cursor up 1 position
nudgeup=`tput cuu 2`   # save it for later
nudgeleft=`tput cub 2`   
echo -n $nudgeup $nudgeleft
```

See a couple of sections after the ANSI section in the BASH prompt howto.

tput also returns an exit code that tells you if something is not supported.