# perl - make beautiful console output for progress of threads

Tags: perl, terminal, console, printf

All of my threads want to print their progresses to the same line of terminal. I can't make them choose different lines. How can I handle it? (linux & windows, if it possible)

edit:

I have tried two variants:

1.

When I print '\n', lines go down, \b do not erase \n characters:

```
if ( !($x % 10) )
  {
    local $| = 1; # Or use IO::Handle; STDOUT->autoflush;
    # remove prev progress
    print "\b" x length($progressString) if defined $progressString;
    # do lots of processing, update $counter
    $progressString = "Thread #$tid.  $x / $length1"; # No more newline
    print $progressString; # Will print, because auto-flush is on
  }
```

2.

similarly

```
my $progress = Term::ProgressBar->new($length1);
$progress->update($x);
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "progresses"? A dot? A character? A number?

Comment: A number, or a filling progress bar.

Comment: Could you use [`lock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lock.html) on a shared variable to avoid different threads printing at the same time?

Comment: It is not a problem, when thread prints. It is a problem, where it prints. I want, each thread prints to its own line in a console. But the caret is only one. So each thread erases and writes to one line, so there is blinking several different progress bars. I what to know, how can I replace caret to one line up? to manually separate the lines of threads. Or there is another way.

Comment: You can move the cursor up and down on a terminal window as described here: [Set or change vertical position of the cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259311/set-or-change-vertical-position-of-the-cursor)

Comment: It is for bash script, I have tried next: 
           *print  "\n"   x $tid; # (thread id)
           print  "\b"   x length($progressString) if defined $progressString;
           print  "\e[A" x $tid, "\r"; # "\033[A" x $tid*
It is not working

Comment: This works fine in `gnome-terminal` : `perl -E 'say "\e[1A123456789\e[0m"'`..  It will print the text `"123456789"` 1 line above the current cursor in the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84314/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-so-olitary).

Comment: I've installed "Win32::Console::ANSI" module, and now it seems, the script is working. No Idea, how will it work in Linux server. Thank you, for your recommendations. (working varint  *print "\e[A" x $tid*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working variant of my script follows:

```
use Win32::Console::ANSI; # for Windows and nothing for linux
# ...
#---OUTPUT----------------------
if ( !($x % 10) ) {
  local $| = 1;
  # Choose the line for thread ($i - thread_id)
  print  "\n" x $i;
  # Remove prev. progress
  print  "\b" x length($progressString) if defined $progressString;

  # Do lots of processing, update
  $progressString = " Thread #$i.  $x / $length1";
  print $progressString; # Will print, because auto-flush is on
  print  "\e[A" x $i, "\r"; # Back to begin before printing
}
#-------------------------------
```