# How to update a line in bash script if condition is met

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script to check if all my microservices are up. I would like to print out the names of all my services and when the service is up I would like to add to the end of the line which contains the name of that service to say that it is up. For example:

```
service1: starting...
service2: starting...
service3: starting...
```

When service1 is up, I would like to update line 1 but not rewrite the names of the services everytime I go through a for loop. So the total script output should be like this:

```
service1: up
service2: starting...
service3: starting...
```

Currently, my bash script is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

services=( \
  service1 \
  service2 \
  service3
)

mgmt_ports=( 10091 10090 10101 )
services_up=( )

service_up () {
  url="http://localhost:$1/actuator/health"
  response=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $url)
  echo $response
  return $response
}

echo -e "Checking that all micro services are up and running ... \n"

#while [ ${#services_up[@]} -ne ${#services[@]} ]; do
    for index in ${!services[@]}; do
      echo "Checking if ${services[$index]} is up ..."

      if [[ ! " ${services_up[@]} " =~ "${services[$index]}" ]]; then
          response=$(service_up ${mgmt_ports[$index]})
          echo $response
          if [ $response == 200 ]; then
            services_up=( "${services_up[@]}" ${services[$index]} )
          fi
      fi
    done
#done
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You're allowed to use newlines in a literal array declaration: line continuations are not required.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259311/set-or-change-vertical-position-of-the-cursor

Comment: There's too many extraneous details. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)